# Why does error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute" in Flask only sometimes fire, and not constantly?

Tags: python, html, mongodb, flask, pymongo

Building a Flask app, and trying to alter the selection of entries/cards by date/popularity. I'm stuck here because this error is not constant, it fires occasionally. I hoped that I'd get this sort function working properly then see to this problem, I thought it was only a minor bug. However, now the error fires much more regularly and I'm dreading that I've just wasted my time entirely on this method; but I don't know.

**App.py**

```
def tester(page):

    limit = 6
    offset = (int(page) - 1) * limit

    requested = request.args.get('fromHTMLchoice')
    print(requested)
    requestChoice = requested.split()
    a = requestChoice[0]
    b = requestChoice[1]
    convertChoice = tuple(a[2:-2], int(b[:-1]))

    sagas_pages = sagas.find().sort(
                        [convertChoice]).skip(offset).limit(limit)

    return render_template(
                "tester.html",
                sagas_pages=sagas_pages, page=page
                      )
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="{{url_for('tester', page=1)}}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Please select</span>
                        <select name="fromHTMLchoice" class="selectpicker form-control">
                            <option value= "('totalLikes', -1)">Likes</option>
                            <option value= "('totalLikes', 1)">Dislikes</option>
                            <option value= "('_id', -1)">Most_Recent</option>
                            <option value= "('_id', 1)">Least_Recent</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**Error**

```
None
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jul/2020 18:07:40] "GET /tester/1 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/workspace/.pip-modules/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/workspace/sagacity/app.py", line 94, in tester
    requestChoice = requested.split()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That AttributeError is downstream of the problem. The problem to debug is why

```
requested = request.args.get('fromHTMLchoice')
print(requested)
```

someones prints `None`, as is does at the top of the log. The safe bet is that, somehow, `tester` is getting invoked by way of a URL that doesn't have a `fromHTMLChoice` parameter.